# Sending mail through WebMail account in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, smtpclient

I have a domain on which i have uploaded my ASP.NET MVC site, also using the cpanel i have created some mail accounts. Now when im trying to send email, i am getting error.Have a look at my code ::

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("webmail-ac@domain.com");
message.To.Add("example@hotmail.com");
message.Subject = "Welcome.";
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Body = "this is my test email body";
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtpClient.Host = "Domain-IP";
smtpClient.Port = 25;
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("webmail-ac@domain.com", "Password");
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, 
    X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{ return true; };
smtpClient.Send(message);
```

But i am getting below described error ::

> Service not available, closing transmission channel.The server response was: Cannot connect to SMTP server [domain-ip] ([domain-ip]:25), connect error 10060.

Can anyone help me in this issue?

Comment: `smtpClient.Host = "Domain-IP";` is that pseudo code? If not, then you need real host of a mailserver...

Comment: Can you telnet to the SMTP server? Does it allow connections? Does it work without SSL?

Comment: @MaxKlaxx--i have also tried _smptClient.Host="mail.domain-name.com", but this is also not working.

Comment: ok i tried your code the with my own mailserver without ssl `smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;` and it works

Comment: usually ssl-connections also use port 465 `smtpClient.Port = 465;` It's worth a try. :-)

Comment: @Ignas---using telnet also im getting the same error.

Comment: @MaxKlaxx--i tried smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;, but still same error.

Comment: do i need to set anything in web.config file ??
or do i need to check/set anything in windows firewall or something ???

Comment: No, you do not need a extra config-file, all settings are present. Did you test the mail server with a regular e-mail program? You may be a problem with the mail server itself. (firewall, service etc...)

Comment: Hosting provider has provided me the url from where i can access those email account that i created using the CPANEL.It looks like "http://webmail.mydomain.com/".I can access my ac by login into this url but i dnt know how to use which settings. I need to solve this ASAP

Answer (score 0):

Please add below line just above credentials and try if it will help:

```
smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
```

Comment: Still same error. I guess there is something wrong with the settings that i am using or webmail doesnt support sending mail, not sure.